# Setting session timeout of only one session

Tags: c#, session

So, I know that there is something like this

```
  <configuration>
    <system.web>
      <sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
    </system.web>
  </configuration>
```

But how can I set a time for one sessions, for example for `Session["Kappa"]` and make it lasts for only 10 minutes without touching others sesions.

@to my defense, that similiar post wast created 5 years ago. It states that there is no way to set a time for specific session. I belive that after 5 years there could be a way *_ *

Comment: It was 5 years ago and I miseed this thread. Is it still impossible to set a time of specific session? If yes, that kind of suck q_ q

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Session Timeout manually using the following:

```
Session.Timeout = 60
```

You can read more here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525473(v=vs.90).aspx